# C# Async pass reference to other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference

I am trying to load a database context in a separate thread. And then update a form's display once finished.

Could anyone advise me on the proper approach to do this.

At the moment my context is loaded, but my _context does not seem to return the Context:

```
    public static ProjectEntities Context = new ProjectEntities();

    public static void LoadAsync(ref ProjectEntities _context, Type _table)
    {
        LoadAsyncImpl(_table);
        _context = Context;
    }

    private static async void LoadAsyncImpl(Type _table)
    {
        ProjectEntities _context = new ProjectEntities();
        await _context.Set(_table).LoadAsync();
        Context = _context;

    }
}
```

Comment: Two extremely bad ideas in one place: `async void` should be avoided unless for event handlers and `DbContext`s should **absolutely never** be static

Comment: Your `LoadSyncImpl` will not get a chance to finish after the second line, because you are not `await`ing it

Comment: if LoadAsyncImpl() is async and must change Context then you start it, don't wait for the and and try to use new context (which is may be not set yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using WinForms, you might try something like this. Note that `_context` is no longer static.

```
private ProjectEntities _context;

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private async void MainForm_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await LoadAsync()
        .ContinueWith(x => {
            if (!x.IsFaulted)
            {
                _context = x.Result;
                Text = "Loaded";
                /* any other stuff on the main UI thread after loading */
            }
            else
            {
                /* and don't forget that sometimes things fail */
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private async Task<ProjectEntities> LoadAsync()
{
    var context = new ProjectEntities();
    await context.Set(...).LoadAsync();
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing